# What is meant by "modified by Community"?

Tags: support, community-user

What is meant by "modified by Community"?

[image]

Also, in this case no edits or modifications are visible to me.

So,then what actually is this modification & what purpose does it serve?

Comment: Community is a bot that randomly bumps old questions so they get more attention; see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48578/what-can-cause-a-question-to-be-bumped

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Okay but what did the bot do in this case to bump the question?i mean in what way?No modification or edits are visible to me.

Comment: Yeah, it does nothing at all to the question.  The bot just makes the system think the question has been edited so that the question will be bumped.

Comment: Oh such a  wise bot. :)

Comment: Inshort, it's a bot :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many posts on the main meta, which are described below:

[Anomalous community user activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43015/163449)

[Why does a question appear as modified by the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6981/163449)

[What does “modified 17m ago Community♦ 1” mean](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247392/163449)

[Please do not “lie” that the Community user “modified” the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247392/163449)

[Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184992/why-does-the-community-user-approve-and-reject-edits)

According to their rule, we cannot mark any duplicate from main meta to here, hence just copy pasting.

Hope that helps.